# Convert Multipolygon Geojson to multiple geojson polygons?

Tags: javascript, polygon, geojson, node-js

I see a lot of questions going from `Polygons` to `MultiPolygon`, but is there some easy way to go the other way around? It would also be useful to preserve the attributes from the `MultiPolygon` to apply to the new `Polygons`.

Comment: In what context? Nodejs, openlayers, database, etc.

Comment: I have Postgis and nodejs available for this project

Comment: Do you want to keep the properties of the multipolygon in the new polygons?

Comment: What do you mean? Like the projection type?

Comment: No, that applies to the whole GeoJSON feature collection. But each individual geometry has its own set of properties. See, http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples

Comment: Yes ideally those would be saved although currently i don't have use for them.

Comment: Ideally if there was a lossless interconversion between multipolygon to single polygons that would be nice.

Comment: OK, I'll post something tomorrow, if no one else does. Have to go, sorry.

Comment: As promised, I have posted an answer which I hope will help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a simple Multipolygon such as the one below,

```
mp=
  {
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
        [
            [-99.028, 46.985], [-99.028, 50.979],
            [-82.062, 50.979], [-82.062, 47.002],
            [-99.028, 46.985]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [-109.028, 36.985], [-109.028, 40.979],
            [-102.062, 40.979], [-102.062, 37.002],
            [-109.028, 36.985]
        ]
     ]
  ]
}
```

then using Javascript/Nodejs you can access each constituent Polygon using forEach, and write out a new Polygon using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
mp.coordinates.forEach(function(coords){
   var feat={'type':'Polygon','coordinates':coords};
   console.log(JSON.stringify(feat));
   }
);
```

You could also access them directly in a loop, if you prefer a less functional way, indexed on mp.coordinates.length eg,

```
for (var i=0;i<mp.coordinates.length;i++){   
   var feat={'type':'Polygon','coordinates':mp.coordinates[i]};
   console.log(JSON.stringify(feat));
}
```

If you are dealing with a FeatureCollection, where you might have an array of feature, each containing a MultiPolygon, eg,

```
mp = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
     {
      "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "MultiPolygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [[
              [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0],
              [100.0, 0.0]
            ]],
            [[
             [0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0],
             [0.0, 0.0]
           ]]          
         ]
     },
      "properties": {
      "prop1": {
        "this": "that"
      },
      "prop0": "value0"
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can use forEach to get to each feature, and then access each Polygon within each Multipolygon simply by looping through the array, as the first dimension of the coordinates array, is the index into each Polygon. Note, you can also save the properties, and assign them to each new Polygon feature.

```
 mp.features.forEach(function(feat){
   var geom=feat.geometry; 
   var props=feat.properties;
   if (geom.type === 'MultiPolygon'){
      for (var i=0; i < geom.coordinates.length; i++){
          var polygon = {
               'type':'Polygon', 
               'coordinates':geom.coordinates[i],
               'properties': props};
          console.log(JSON.stringify(polygon));
      }
    }
 });
```

If you want something more sophisticated, you could look into modifying the [OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js) class.