# Simple way to convert GeoJSON from MultiPolygon into Polygon

Tags: polygon, geojson, convert, multi-polygon

I need a GeoJSON file that simply has the coordinates of the polygons for the boundaries of the provinces of Canada.

I have a GeoJSON file but it has multipolygons and my software does not support multipolygons. How can I convert the multipolygons to simple polygons?

Of course, if the geometry of the province consists of disconnected regions with pieces of other provinces in the interior of a given province, then it wouldn't make sense to try to convert it to a single polygon. However, I am not aware of Canadian provinces having pieces of other provinces in their interior.

I have seen posts with what looks like SQL server code; I don't know what application they are using. I do not have SQL server on my machine.

Comment: You can try with this. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121396/convert-multipolygon-geojson-to-multiple-geojson-polygons?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Multipolygon Geojson to multiple geojson polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121396/convert-multipolygon-geojson-to-multiple-geojson-polygons)

Comment: I was mistaken to say that I could not use multipolygons. Javascript leaflet seems to work fine with the multipolygons